# Jboss EAP 7.2 @RolesAllowed is not working inside implementation class

Tags: ejb, jboss7.x, jboss-eap-7

I have 2 modules, one describes api with just interfaces of controllers and second with implementations.
Example:

Resource interface:

```
@Path("/resource")
public interface Resource {
    @POST
    @Path("/getAll")
    @Produces("application/json")
    Response getAll();
```

Resource implementation:

```
@RequestScoped
@Path("/user")
public class ResourceImpl implements Resource {

    @RolesAllowed({"admin"})
    public Response getAll() {
```

When I login with user that has role "user", I'm not getting 401 or 403 error.
If I add @RolesAllowed({"admin"}) to interface, then it will work as expected. But I believe there should be other solution for it

I tried solution from this topic https://access.redhat.com/solutions/766483 but with no luck
My ejb.xml looks like so:

```
<ejb-jar
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
                           http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_1.xsd"
        version="3.1">

    <enterprise-beans>
           <message-driven>
            *Queues describtion*
           </message-driven>
    </enterprise-beans>

    <assembly-descriptor>
        <method-permission>
            <role-name>admin</role-name>
            <method>
                <ejb-name>ResourceImpl</ejb-name>
                <method-name>*</method-name>
            </method>
        </method-permission>
    </assembly-descriptor>
</ejb-jar>
```

I'm using Jboss EAP 7.2.9

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you have an interface?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli this is the requirement. It has resource dtos and api interface so we can call it in different modules. But we don't need to focus on that so much

Comment: We must focus on that because that's why it doesn't work

Comment: Ok agree with that actually. So any ideas?